# Why does bash variable expansion retain quotes?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

```
> echo "hi"
hi
> VAR='echo "hi"'
> $VAR
"hi"
```

Why is the output of the above commands different?

A similar thing occurs with single quotes:

```
> VAR="echo 'hi'"
> $VAR
> 'hi'
```

Comment: Please do not get in the habit of embedding executable script snippets in variables.  This tends to be [tricky at best](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and [`eval` is a minefield of potential security holes which you must tread very carefully](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Comment: @jw013 Good point and great articles.  I like the quote "Variables hold data, functions hold code." from the first link, but for my usage, the data that is given to a function (in this case, `at`) *is* code.  Any tips on a safer way to organize/collect code that will be given to `at`?

Comment: `at` takes `sh` syntax as input.  Thus generating input for `at` means generating valid, properly quoted `sh` syntax from arbitrary input, which is not trivial, so I'd try to avoid it if at all possible.  It would really help if you could give a little more detail on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to distract with too much detail, but what I'm doing isn't really complicated, IMO.  I'm creating a script that takes a "time" and a "message".  It then runs `at` for the given "time", and tells `at` to run the command `dzen2`.  `dzen2` takes the "message" from stdin, and also uses some other static parameters.  The difficulty is that I need to pipe the "message" parameter from the user into the `dzen2` command, but I'm not actually running `dzen2` myself, I'm telling `at` to do it.

Comment: @jw013 I ended up getting everything to work just fine, by the way.

Comment: "Variables hold data, functions hold code." Unless it's a lisp.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/360966/how-do-i-use-a-bash-variable-string-containing-quotes-in-a-command/936487#936487 || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454526/bash-variable-containing-multiple-args-with-quotes

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The extra pair of quotes would be consumed only by an extra evaluation step. For example forced by `eval`:

```
bash-4.2$ VAR='echo "hi"'

bash-4.2$ $VAR
"hi"

bash-4.2$ eval $VAR
hi
```

But generally is a bad idea to put commands with parameters in one string. Use an array instead:

```
bash-4.2$ VAR=(echo "hi")

bash-4.2$ "${VAR[@]}"
hi
```

Comment: It's also important to note that quotes are evaluated differently; double quotes (") allow evaluation of the enclosed string, single quotes (') print the string as a literal. Example: `"$(ls)"` and `'$(ls)'`. This is the reason why quotes appear in original questions examples.

Comment: An array is also a source of problems. Code belongs to functions, data to variables. The example you present works only because the quotes are removed in the split of the array. A `printf '<%s> ' "${VAR[@]}"` will show that quotes have been removed already. If you set VAR as `VAR=(echo \"hi\")` to actually have quotes, the same problem appears again, `$ ${VAR[@]}` will print `"hi"`

Answer (score 10):

[Quote removal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_07) only occurs on the original input words, *not* on the result of expansions.  Quotes that are part of expanded variables are untouched.

Answer (score 3):

If you step back a bit, you can see why variable substitution absolutely should retain quotes.

The point of quotes in a Unix/Linux/BSD shell is to keep pieces of a string together that would otherwise get parsed as multiple strings.  Since by default a shell uses whitespace as a token separator, a string with spaces (like "one two three") if not quoted or escaped somehow, would get parsed as 3 strings: "one", "two" and "three".

If a programmer wants a string with the value of some variable interpolated:

```
VAR=two
STRING="one $VAR three"
```

the shell should absolutely not remove the quotes: the string containing spaces would get parsed as 3 smaller strings.